# Python tkinter scrollbar doesn't attached well to listbox

Tags: python, listbox, scrollbar, tkinter

SO, I am doing what everyone else says:

```
scrollbar = Scrollbar(frame)

scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

listbox = Listbox(frame, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

listbox.pack()

scrollbar.config(command=listbox.yview)
```

but it seems that the scroll bar is attached to the whole frame and not the listbox itself...
the only thing I am able to do - is use scrollbar.place() instead of pack
and place it next to the listbox, but them its only a 1 size scroll bar and it does not cover the listbox Y-bar only part of it, which is ugly...

can anyone help here?

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You do need to attach the scrollbar to the frame -- But you can easily create a new frame to hold only the scrollbar and the listbox.

e.g.

```
myframe=Frame(frame)
myframe.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
scrollbar = Scrollbar(myframe) 
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
listbox = Listbox(myframe, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set) 
listbox.pack()
scrollbar.config(command=listbox.yview)
```

Comment: @keizer -- frames can be nested however deep you want them.  They're imperative for creating complex layouts with Tkinter.

Comment: ok, I found out what was wrong, the fill=Y inside the new frame should be removed - THANKS!:)

Answer (score 1):

widgets don't attach to each other, they only occupy space inside a container. If you pack the scrollbar on the right, and then pack the listbox on the right, they will appear attached. You can also put the listbox on the left and have it fill in the horizontal direction, or you can pack it anywhere if it fills both directions.

You can also use grid instead of pack; just arrange for them to be in adjacent columns.

So, don't think of "attaching" widgets, think about placing them in containers.